# (Kotlin) Iteration over channel skips every second element

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following code using Kotlin Channels

```
    class TestChannels {
        @Test
        fun testChannels() {
            runBlocking {
                val someNumbers = Channel<Int>(UNLIMITED)
                repeat(100) {
                    someNumbers.send(it)
                }
                someNumbers.close()
                for (number in someNumbers) {
                    println(number)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect it to print

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

However, it somehow skips all the even elements and produces the following

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

It's basically the sample from a documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#closing-and-iteration-over-channels

What am I possibly doing wrong?

UPD: Reproducing on Kotlin 1.8.22, as it creates BufferedChannel
On 1.7.21 did not reproduce, as LinkedListChannel is created. Yet do not have any solution

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: @Tenfour04 which version of Kotlin did you use? I've failed to reproduce it as well at 1.7. On 1.8, though, I have exactly this result

Comment: Tested in 1.9.0. Looks fine in all three versions on Kotlin Playground.

Comment: Maybe also specify your Kotlin coroutines version?